# Symfony2 router returns absolute url with port 80

Tags: php, symfony

When calling:

```
$this->get('router')->generate('...',array(),true)
```

To get an absolute URL from a controller I get a URL with default Port 80:
https://subdomain.mydomain.com:80

How can I get rid of the :80? This only happens in production. On my local machine I don't get the default port in the absolute URL.

Production environment uses a reverse proxy (nginx:443->varnish->apache:80)
The local apache server port is 80 but should be the remote Port 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btw this has been fixed in Symfony 2.3.5
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/65814bae27d6fdb9501a4efd07e6b980353d89bb

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix this by defining the router context in the parameters.yml file like so:

```
router.request_context.host: localhost:8181
router.request_context.scheme: http
router.request_context.base_url: /application/path
```

This will let you generate correct URLs when there is no web context, like in commands or cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You should check: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#line-244, it might be the cause of your problem.

It's also possible it's a caching issue, try debugging using:

```
$this->context->getHttpPort() / ->getHttpsPort()
```

Comment: Ok, now it's clear to me: _SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on" and _SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] = "80". Thats the problem. Don't know how to change the server_port variable :-( I tried mod_rpaf with no success. I think I have a too old version of mod_rpaf installed and don't want to mess my setup. I will just string replace the :80

Comment: would be great if $this->context->getHttpPort() would honor the X-Forwarded-Port header

Comment: hmm the https is on but it's redirected to port 80 ? seems like you don't have the https enable on the apache ... why not redirect nginx to apache:443 ?

Comment: Nginx does all the SSL stuff listening on 443. Nginx then proxies to varnish and the apache is listening on port 80 as varnish backend server. So there is no need for apache to run on 443 with https. All my backend servers are pure http.